# Push to navigationController doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

okay, I completely changed my previous code, this is what I need to the, but the last push to navigation controller is not working

```
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        if let user = userInfo["user"] as? String{
            User.loadUserById(user, completion: {result in
                let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! SWRevealViewController
                let StoryB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let Logged : UITabBarController = StoryB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                rootViewController.setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.Left, animated: true)
                let profileViewController : UserProfileVC = StoryB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserProfileVC") as! UserProfileVC
                profileViewController.user = result
                rootViewController.pushFrontViewController(Logged, animated: true)
                let wc = rootViewController.frontViewController as! UITabBarController
                if let wcc = wc.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController{
                    wcc.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
                }

            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that "TabBarController" is the correct identifier for your TabBarController ?

Comment: I have set it as StoryBoardID, but I think TabBarController is not right Controller I want to present. I have edited my question a while ago, I'm sorry but I can't post better picture of my storyboard, thank you

Comment: What is the crashing line ? I can't see anything on your screenshots. What viewController would you like to display ?

Comment: the crashing line is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, ->  0x1006165dc <+44>:  brk    #0x1, I would like to display UserProfileVC, which is the last one in the storyboard picture st the bottom. I could do it but then my TabBarController and SWRevealController disappeared

Comment: or maybe I could set as presented any viewcontroller and perform a segue from there?

Comment: i changed presentViewController to pushViewController and now I can display the tabBarController, however now I need to push UserProfileController to tabBarController

Answer (score 0):

it was wrong that I was pushing new tabbarcontroller to root, this code works

```
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
       if let type = userInfo["type"] as? String{
            if type == "wink" || type == "met" {
                if let user = userInfo["user"] as? String{
                    User.loadUserById(user, completion: {result in
                        if let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? SWRevealViewController{

                            let StoryB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            rootViewController.setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.Left, animated: true)
                            let profileViewController : UserProfileVC = StoryB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserProfileVC") as! UserProfileVC
                            profileViewController.user = result
                            if let tabBar = rootViewController.frontViewController as? UITabBarController{
                                if let navigationController = tabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController{
                                    navigationController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    })

                }
            }
        }

    }
```